# How to properly abstract data loading when using composition API and onBeforeRouteUpdate?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, reusability

I have a Vue 3 single-page component whose script part roughly looks like this:

```js
export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    id: String,
  },
  setup(props) {
    const error = ref<boolean>(false)
    const thisCategory = ref<CategoryDetails>()
    const subcategories= ref<Category[]>()

    const fetchData = (categoryId: string) => {
      fetchCategoryDetails(categoryId)
        .then((v) => {
          thisCategory.value = v
          subcategories.value = v.child_categories
        })
        .catch(() => error.value = true)
    }

    fetchData(props.id || "")

    onBeforeRouteUpdate((to) => fetchData(to.params.id as string))

    return {
      error,
      thisCategory,
      subcategories,
    }
  }
})
```

`fetchData` is the function I use to fetch the data I need for the view. As you can see, I use it twice: once in setup() itself to load the data when the component is first instantiated, and then again `onBeforeRouteUpdate` so that links inside this component which link to the same component (but with different data to fetch) will actually load the new data.

I anticipate that I will need to do this for other components too, so I want to abstract this behaviour away, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Another issue is that when I call the function directly, I get the ID from the `props`, but inside the route guard I have to use `to.params`, or else the new ID will not be loaded correctly.

How can I abstract this procedure away in a single function that I can simply call in each component (perhaps passing in just a closure like `fetchData`), that will handle both loading the data initially and when navigation changes?

Comment: you want only to reuse the function or all the properties and the function?

Comment: I would like to be able to use that on different functions and properties. Here I have `fetchCategoryDetails`  but in another component I might have `fetchItemDetails` or `fetchItemList` etc. And I might need to only get one item like `thisCategory` but also possibly more (like `subcategories`).

Answer (score 0):

### Update

If you want to abstract the `error` and adding of the `onBeforeRouteUpdate` listener only, you'll still need to handle the population of the variables through the parent, so you'd need to process the updating of local variables such as `thisCategory` and `subcategories` through a method that you pass.

```
import { ref, computed } from "vue";
import { onBeforeRouteUpdate } from "vue-router";

export const STATE = {
  INIT: "INIT",
  LOADING: "LOADING",
  SUCCESS: "SUCCESS",
  ERROR: "ERROR",
};

export const withFetchResource = (fetchMethod, id) => {
  const loadingState = ref(STATE.INIT);
  const error = computed(() => loadingState.value === STATE.ERROR);

  const fetchData = (resourceId) => {
    loadingState.value = STATE.LOADING;
    fetchMethod(resourceId)
      .then((response) => {
        loadingState.value = LOADING.SUCCESS;
        return response;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        loadingState.value = LOADING.ERROR;
      });
  };

  fetchData(id.value);

  onBeforeRouteUpdate((to) => fetchData(to.params.id as string));

  return { error, loadingState, fetchData };
};
```

```
import { ref, defineComponent } from "vue";
import { STATE, fetchCategoryDetails } from "./myApi.ts";
import { withFetchResource } from "./withFetchResource.ts";

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    id: String,
  },
  setup(props) {
    const thisCategory = ref<CategoryDetails>();
    const subcategories = ref<Category[]>();

    const categoryFetchHandler = (id) => {
      return fetchCategoryDetails(id).then((v) => {
        thisCategory.value = v;
        subcategories.value = v.child_categories;
      });
    };

    const { error: categoryError } = withFetchResource(
      categoryFetchHandler,
      props.id || ""
    );

    return {};
  },
});
```

---

I think you may be able to move the whole of it into another file/method.

```
// withFetchCategoryDetail.ts
import {ref} from "vue";
import {onBeforeRouteUpdate} from "vue-router";
import {fetchCategoryDetails} from "./myApi.ts";

export const withFetchCategoryDetail = (props) => {
  const error = ref<boolean>(false)
  const thisCategory = ref<CategoryDetails>()
  const subcategories= ref<Category[]>()

  const fetchData = (categoryId: string) => {
    fetchCategoryDetails(categoryId)
      .then((v) => {
        thisCategory.value = v
        subcategories.value = v.child_categories
      })
      .catch(() => error.value = true)
  }

  fetchData(props.id || "")

  onBeforeRouteUpdate((to) => fetchData(to.params.id as string))

  return {
    error,
    thisCategory,
    subcategories,
  }
}
```

```
import { ref, onBeforeRouteUpdate, defineComponent } from "vue";
import { withFetchCategoryDetail } from "./withFetchCategoryDetail.ts";

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    id: String,
  },
  setup(props) {
    return {
      ...withFetchCategoryDetail(props)
    };
  },
});
```

I haven't tested whether `onBeforeRouteUpdate` will work within the hook method, but can't see why it wouldn't

Comment: If `onBeforeRouteUpdate` doesn't work, you can instead use a `watch`. In fact this is my preferred method for updating a component based on url parameters because you can set the `immediate: true` flag to handle the initial load too

Comment: agreed, would also make it easier to hook to other methods if needed

Comment: Using a watch would partially defeat the purpose of using the composition API though, right? Isn't the whole point of it that code can be refactored and simply be imported in setup() without needing to change other parts of the component?

Anyway I will test this later this evening when I get the chance; it's essential that the route guard works.

Comment: However, I was hoping for a solution that would let me make the code more general: with this one I would only be able to fetch CategoryDetails objects, but what if I have a very similar `fetchData` function on another component, but which fetches `ItemDetails` instead? Refactoring each as individual functions when almost all the code is the same seems wasteful and hard to maintain.

Comment: which part are you abstracting then? Just the `error` and the `onBeforeRouteUpdate` hook? seems like all other variables would have to be provided.

Comment: this bs is why i find vue so frustrating